How to find the maximum value in a column from a nested subquery?
I have the following table



student.ID
student.name
student.dept_name
student.tot_cred




128
'Zhang'
'Comp. Sci.'
102


12345
'Shankar'
'Comp. Sci.'
32


19991
'Brandt'
'History'
80


23121
'Chavez'
'Finance'
110


44553
'Peltier'
'Physics'
56


45678
'Levy'
'Physics'
46


54321
'Williams'
'Comp. Sci.'
54


55739
'Sanchez'
'Music'
38


70557
'Snow'
'Physics'
0



I want to find the department that has most students enrolled in, and when that works, I want to find if two departments have the same number of students. I want to output the department name that is smaller alphabetically.
I tried to mimic this solution which does not include a sub query:
how-to-find-max-value-and-its-associated-field-values-in-sql
which is exactly what I need but with the count subquery included.
SELECT sub.dept_name, max_dep
FROM (SELECT student.dept_name, COUNT(student.dept_name) as dep_count
      FROM student GROUP BY student.dept_name) as sub 
WHERE sub.max_dep = (select max(dep_count) from sub )

This gives a syntax error and it does not work.
I am using this website to check my query (in the student Table).
I also don't want to use the ORDER BY then limit to one row answer, I prefer using the WHERE clause to check for the maximum, but I am not sure how to achieve it

If you don't want to use ORDER BY then you should specify why, because that would be the way to do it.

It's because I thought there might be an answer using the Where clause, I just want to understand different approaches on this.

Since I am testing it on that website they support basic SQL, but I can also use MySQL

Use ORDER BY, don't do anything else. Other options are worse readable, slower, don't have any advantage. No idea why you urgently want to write bad SQL queries rather than good ones. Stop it! If you want to learn things, focus on difficult and meaningful questions, not on such bad ideas.

Sample data is great. but can you also specify the expected result. I.e. provide a complete [mcve].

BTW, https://dbfiddle.uk/ is great for simple testing purposes. Supports several major dbms's.

You can do a basic WHERE NOT EXISTS subquery, to avoid the ORDER BY.

https://dbfiddle.uk/KnRQi_iE, @ValNiks fiddle, having a NOT EXISTS query added at the and.

@JhonSilver Please note that Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned and read Help Center: AI policy.
It is not permitted to use AI tools to generate or reword content that you post on Stack Overflow. Besides that AI tools are known for writing nonsense and there is no point in asking people here to debug broken code AI has written.

See example
select min(dept_name) dept_name,cnt
from (
   select dept_name,count(*) cnt 
   from student 
   group by dept_name
   having count(*)
      =(select max(cnt) 
        from(
             select count(*) cnt 
             from student group by dept_name
            )as counts
       )
)max_depts
group by cnt

Let's consider the request in parts.

Count students in dept

select dept_name,count(*) cnt 
   from student 
   group by dept_name

Output is



dept_name
cnt




Comp. Sci.
3


Finance
1


History
1


Music
1


Physics
3




Calculate max count students in dept.

(select max(cnt) 
        from(
             select count(*) cnt 
             from student group by dept_name
            )as counts
       )

There subquery counts result is (cnt)(3),(1),(1),(1),(3).
Then select max(cnt) from counts result is (3).

Use HAVING clause to filter this output  (subquery max_depts)

select dept_name,count(*) cnt 
   from student 
   group by dept_name
   having count(*)
      =(... ->3  )




dept_name
cnt




Comp. Sci.
3


Physics
3




Subquery max_depts may have 1 or more rows, where cnt is the same.
So we take alphabetically least value by min(dept_name) with group by cnt.
This value (cnt) is the same for all rows. So, we get 1 row as result.

select min(dept_name) dept_name,cnt
from ( ... )max_depts
group by cnt




dept_name
cnt




Comp. Sci.
3



Another example
select min(dept_name) dept_name,cnt
from (
   select dept_name,count(*) cnt 
   from student 
   group by dept_name
)as depts_counts
where cnt=(select max(cnt) 
        from(
             select count(*) cnt 
             from student group by dept_name
            )as counts
       )
group by cnt

There
1.Calculate count of students in each dept.
2.Filter by condition cnt=3. Filter is applied before grouping.
3.Group by cnt
Try Fiddle
